# Using Q on nodejs not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have the following functions:

```
function search(response) {
    console.log("1");
    step1().then(step2(response)).done();
    console.log("4");
}

var step1=function()
{
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    searchOperations.performSearch(deferred);
    return deferred.promise;
}

var step2 = function(response) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("someresult" + "\n");
    response.end();
    console.log("2");
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

and that one:

```
function performSearch(deferred) {

    console.log("Request handler 'search' was called.");
    var qryObj = {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        }
    };
    elasticSearchClient.search(index, type, qryObj).
        on('data', function (data) {
           // console.log(data)
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("3");
                deferred.resolve();
            }, 5000);
          //  deferred.resolve();
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .exec();
}
```

The expected output is: 1, 4 , 3, 2

However I get this output: 
1
2
4
3

Why step 2 is invoked before step 3?

My intention is to print(step 2) the results only after I get them from the searching callback (step 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is, that you are calling step2 instead of passing it.

```
function search(response) {
    console.log("1");
    step1().then(step2(response)).done();
    console.log("4");
}
```

should be

```
function search(response) {
    console.log("1");
    step1().then(function () {
        step2(response);
    }).done();
    console.log("4");
}
```

this is equivalent to something like this:

```
function search(response) {
    console.log("1");
    function callStep2() {
        step2(response);
    }
    step1().then(callStep2).done();
    console.log("4");
}
```

Comment: You were right. that solved it. but I still didnt understand when you saying 'passing' it? Mybe I miss something basic here? in my original code I am passing step2 which is a reference to a function. why did you wrap that within another function ?

Comment: if you did `.then(step2)` that would be passing the function step2, but `.then(step2(response))` would immediately execute step2 with response and pass the return value of step2.

Comment: I understand. but still not sure I understand it all through. why when using step2(response) is actually invoking the method and not passing it? why the response argument actually matters?

Comment: `step2` doesn't call the function, `step2()` calls it without arguments. `step2(response)` calls it with response as the argument. You can't set an argument without calling the function, so I pass an anonymous function that calls step2 with the response argument. PS. I edited the answer to be more clear

Comment: I understood your solution I just missing something basic - why when you calling a function with param you actually call it and not passing it? talking generally

Comment: yes, calling a function with a param NEVER passes the function, it always calls it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to shorten this code(Take off the steps) and call the functions inline one after another? could you show me how?